# python is not recognised

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to install pylint as I am using VS code but I keep getting this error code:

```
PS C:\Users\Alex> python -m pip install pylint
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python -m pip install pylint
+ ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am running Windows 10 64bit.

EDIT:

I tried using 'py' instead of 'python' and it worked.

PS C:\Users\Alex> py -m pip install pylint

Comment: Is python in your `PATH`?

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Sol 1) In System Path Environment variable --> C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts;

Sol 2) Run the command line as Administrator

Comment: I am using Python 3.5, should I present it as (C:\Python35;C:\Python35\Tools\Scripts;) ?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6 in my other system.

Path -- > C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python36\;

So. i will say copy the path of where exactly your python 3.5 installed.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the 3.6 version and realise that there is an add 'path' in the installer and it worked.